# Uncaught TypeError: btnz.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

```
const btnList = [
    {
        id: 'all',
        content: 'All'
    },
    {
        id: 'br',
        content: 'breakfast'
    },
    {
        id: 'dn',
        content: 'dinner'
    }
]
const btnz = document.querySelector('.btnz');

 // for version 1 I declared newBtn beforehand: let newBtn = ''
 btnList.forEach(btn => {
        // version 1: 
        newBtn += `<button id="${btn.id}">${btn.content}</button>`
        // version 2:
        let newBtn = document.createElement('button');
        newBtn.setAttribute('id', btn.id);
        newBtn.textContent = btn.content;
        btnz.appendChild(newBtn);
    })
```

This is my JS and I have just simple div with class btnz where I want to append new dynamic buttons. Could you kindly explain what is the problem? Why none of versions does not work.

Comment: Can you show how are you initialising `btnz`

Comment: your question is incomplete : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

[`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) ***NodeList***. You should use index.

If you have single element with the class `btnz` then I will suggest you to use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns the ***first*** Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const btnList = [
        {
            id: 'all',
            content: 'All'
        },
        {
            id: 'br',
            content: 'breakfast'
        },
        {
            id: 'dn',
            content: 'dinner'
        }
    ]
     // for version 1 I declared newBtn beforehand: let newBtn = ''
     const btnz = document.querySelector('.btnz');
     btnList.forEach(btn => {
        // version 1: 
        //newBtn += `<button id="${btn.id}">${btn.content}</button>`
        // version 2:
        let newBtn = document.createElement('button');
        newBtn.setAttribute('id', btn.id);
        newBtn.textContent = btn.content;
        btnz.appendChild(newBtn);
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="btnz"></div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to select my DOM elements with getElement.. instead querySelectors?

Comment: @UlviEnzo, you do not have any element with class `btnz`. Also, `querySelectorAll()` returns node list, you should index. like btnz[0].appendChild(..... Though I prefer `querySelector()` you have only single element, in that case you do not need to use index:)

Comment: I have, I added after asking question. But it had on my code. .btnz is just simple <div class="btnz"></div> and selected in JS code.

Comment: @UlviEnzo, I have the question with some description:)

Comment: I am probably missing something. I did not get what is the real problem here (after putting your version still get errors), but thanks for help

Comment: @UlviEnzo, the only possible issue code be that your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded, to solve such issue you can either palce your code at the bottom of the body or wrap code with `DOMContentLoaded`. Please the updated answer:)

Comment: So, I wrapped it in window.addEventListener('load',myfunction(){...code here..}). I want you to explain me please, why this code is not working first of all? >>>     let newBtn = '';
    btnList.forEach(btn => {
      newBtn += `<button id="${btn.id}">${btn.content}</button>`
    })
    btnz.innerHTML = newBtn;
Here my goal is to create collection of strings and after creation 'push' them into btnz div. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

As in version 1 you are getting `newBtn` as string, so you need to do `innerHTML` to add inside DOM.

```js
const btnList = [{
    id: 'all',
    content: 'All'
  },
  {
    id: 'br',
    content: 'breakfast'
  },
  {
    id: 'dn',
    content: 'dinner'
  }
];

let newBtn = '';
const btnz = document.querySelector("div.btnz");
btnList.forEach(btn => {
  // version 1: 
  newBtn += `<button id="${btn.id}">${btn.content}</button>`
})
btnz.innerHTML = newBtn;
```

```html
<div class="btnz"></div>
```

For version 2 you need to `appendChild` on `NodeElement`

```js
const btnList = [{
    id: 'all',
    content: 'All'
  },
  {
    id: 'br',
    content: 'breakfast'
  },
  {
    id: 'dn',
    content: 'dinner'
  }
]

let newBtn = '';
const btnz = document.querySelector("div.btnz");
btnList.forEach(btn => {
  // version 2:
  let newBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newBtn.setAttribute('id', btn.id);
  newBtn.textContent = btn.content;
  btnz.appendChild(newBtn);
})
```

```html
<div class="btnz"></div>
```

Comment: I did as you said, I added innerHTML but still can not append it to btnz, it returns similar error. Would you mind to explain what to do for second version by your code please?

Comment: Your second code is perfect, just comment the first version and `run`. It will work like a charm

Comment: Your answer for the first version: before creating 2nd version I did same as you wrote. But I get an error as: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at

Comment: @UlviEnzo If you're getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` then please see how you select the dom element i.e using `querySelector`, `findElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`. There must be something wrong. As in my case I've used `const btnz = document.querySelector("div.btnz");`